# Fazer busca em 3 tabelas Mysql não relacionadas

Tags: mysql

Em um sistema, tenho 03 tipos de busca interna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria de buscar em 03 tabelas não relacionadas:

> tabela1, tabela2 e tabela3

Para isso, tentei os comandos abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela1` WHERE NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' UNION SELECT * FROM `tabela2` WHERE NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' UNION SELECT * FROM `tabela3` WHERE NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%'
```

A de cima, deu o erro abaixo:

> ## 1222 - Os comandos SELECT usados têm diferente número de colunas

Tentei essa busca e também não consegui:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela1`, `tabela2`, `tabela3` WHERE tabela1.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' OR tabela2.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%'  OR tabela3.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%'
```

Ele me retorna todos os nomes, independente se são Davi ou não. Como posso fazer essa busca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você não está usando o LIKE para fazer sua busca. O certo é:

```
(SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE tabela1.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Dav%')
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM tabela2 WHERE tabela2.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Dav%')
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM tabela3 WHERE tabela3.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Dav%')
ORDER BY NomeUsuarios;
```

**[Veja funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8286ae/1)**

**EDIT**

Para selecionar TODOS, basta você usar o UNION ALL. Assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE tabela1.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Dav%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tabela2 WHERE tabela2.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Dav%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tabela3 WHERE tabela3.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Dav%'
ORDER BY NomeUsuarios;
```

O UNION simples executa um DISTINCT no SELECT. Por isso ele ignora resultados iguais.

**[Veja o resultado aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9886a/9)**

Comment: Pessoal, na verdade estou usando o Like. No post coloquei manualmente e acabei colocando de forma errada, mas ajustei o meu post. Acredito que seja algum problema na configuração do mysql local ou algo assim. Vou testar remotamente para ver se funciona.

Comment: Sobre o problema do erro #1222, corrigi da seguinte maneira, alterei a query para:  `SELECT tabela1.NomeUsuarios FROM tabela1 WHERE tabela1.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' UNION SELECT tabela2.NomeUsuarios FROM tabela2 WHERE tabela2.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' UNION SELECT tabela3.NomeUsuarios FROM tabela3 WHERE tabela3.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%'`, porém mesmo tendo o nome Davi nas 03 tabelas, ele só me retornou 1. Na verdade preciso trazer os 03 resultados das 03 tabelas.

Comment: @Fox.11 da uma olhada na minha edição.

Comment: Obrigado Andrei. Funcionou!

Comment: @Fox.11 tranquilo! Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

tenta assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE tabela1.NomeUsuarios = 'Davi%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tabela2 WHERE tabela2.NomeUsuarios = 'Davi%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tabela3 WHERE tabela3.NomeUsuarios = 'Davi%'
```

Testei assim e funcionou:

```
SELECT * FROM 
tabela1,
tabela2,
tabela3
WHERE
tabela1.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' AND
tabela2.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' AND
tabela2.NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%' AND
```

O `%` deve ser usado com o operador `LIKE`.

> [Na referência que estou sugerindo, diferente do exemplo que dei, explica melhor o funcionamento do **UNION**, talvez possa te ajudar.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Olá Wees. Já tentei dessa forma, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Da uma olhada na referencia que citei agr, talvez ajude a entender o UNION, vou procurar outras formas para mostrar

Comment: Certo Wees. Darei uma olhada. Obrigado.

Comment: Achei uma solução que funcionou nos meus testes, da uma olhada

Comment: só altere para `OR` no lugar de `AND` no seu segundo `SELECT ` pois neste segundo que você fez ele só retornará se todas as tabelas tiverem o valor `LIKE 'Davi%'`. Eu acredito que não é isso que ele quer pois o UNION funciona como se fosse um OR e ele colocou o OR no segundo select dele da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar se existe um registro que comece com `Davi` em uma das três tabelas usando uma subquery desta forma:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tabela1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM tabela2
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM tabela3
) t
WHERE NomeUsuarios LIKE 'Davi%'
```